# Crucial BX200 SSD Windows 7 Drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ssd

Swapped one of my users to a Crucial BX200-480G SSD from the original 750 GB mostly empty 5400 RPM drive in laptop (HP Pavilion dv7-6130us, Win7 Pro (x64)).

It seems to be working spiffy and fast - but...Windows is using a generic "standard disk" MicroSoft driver dated 2006. Windows says it can't find a better driver. This seems like a terrible idea for an SSD, which the OS **at least** needs to know is an SSD so it's used correctly and not prematurely worn out by actions only appropriate to a spinning disk.

Crucial's only option for getting a driver for the BX200 is an execrable piece of web-browser-based "software" (Crucial Storage Executive) that requires giving Java a level of access that upsets Windows, and which then varies between recognizing the disk but ALSO finding no drivers suitable to it, or not recognizing the disk and providing no information at all. I'm vastly unimpressed.

Wondering if anyone else has run into and/or solved this issue. I have an email into Micron (Crucial) support, but I'm not exactly hopeful that they will be useful, based on why I have to email them at all.

Comment: this is the normal AHCI driver from Microsoft. This is ok. Leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about that generic driver. There is no "SSD" driver required (I'm not sure if such a thing even exists) - Windows 7 automatically knows that the disk is a SSD and uses features such as TRIM.

If you want to make sure TRIM is enabled, simply run the following command at the cmd prompt:

```
fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
```

If you get a `0`, TRIM is enabled correctly. If you get a `1`, TRIM is disabled.

If necessary, TRIM can be enabled by the following command:

```
fsutil behavior set DisableDeleteNotify 0
```